# How not to save a managedobjectcontext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to create a new core data object, and fill it with some information of the subviews on a view. (just to fill an array with template_control objects)

What's the problem?
The object can't be saved, but later on when I do a real save of the `managedobjectcontect`, the  object is saved.

What did I try?
I created a new `managedobjectcontext` which I don't save, but the control is still saved when I do a `savemanagedobjectcontext` on the normal `managedobjectcontext`.

Anyone who has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

```
   Template_Control * temp_control = [NSEntityDescription  
      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Template_Control"
                                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.tmpManagedObjectContext];

for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
    if(![view isEqual:self.templateEditView.leftSideView]){
        NSLog(@"DE TAG VAN DE view is %i",view.tag);

        temp_control.height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.size.height];
        temp_control.width = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.bounds.size.width];

        [temp_control setX:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.frame.origin.x]];
        [temp_control setY:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:view.frame.origin.y]];
        NSLog(@"%i",view.tag);
        [temp_control setControl:[self getControlForTemplateControl:view.tag]];

        [self.controlsOnTemplate addObject:temp_control];
    }
}

NSLog(@"aantal controls: op de template %i", [self.controlsOnTemplate count]);
temp_control = nil;
```

This is image of my table

[image]

To make it a little clearer, here's the code where I save the normal managedobjectcontext:

-(void)saveNewTemplateControls{

```
NSError *error;

//template voor de contorl ophalen
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Template" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",self.template.name];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


NSEntityDescription *entitydescTemplateControl = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Template_Control"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

for(Template_Control *template_control in self.theNewControls){
    NSManagedObject *newtemplatecontrol = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydescTemplateControl
                                                  insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:template_control.width forKey:@"width"];
    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:template_control.height forKey:@"height"];

    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:template_control.x forKey:@"x"];
    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:template_control.y forKey:@"y"];

    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:[results objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"template"];

    [newtemplatecontrol setValue:template_control.control forKey:@"control"];

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean under "object can't be saved"? How is your CD stack initialized, are you using multithreading, do you have some validation rools on attributes?

Comment: I'll make it a little clearer. I want to create an array containing all the subviews on a view, whereafter I create an array with managed objects (template_control), containing the x, y, width, height and the control (entity in my database, getting in another function). later on in my code, I want to add the template (intity in my database) to each of these controls, but the problem is that the managedobjects I create whitout the template propertie filles are also saved.

Comment: In the image I added to my post, you can see the insert that's done whitout the template filled :)

Comment: Ok, and why don't they (ones without template filled) have to be saved on save, if you didn't delete them? If you create something in managedObjectContext it's stays there if you don't delete it. And why do you need to check the underneath DB structure?

Comment: I tried to just create a template_control *templatecontrol, but then I got an error I couldn't find an answer on, so I created it as a managed object. Can I delete them from the managedobjectcontext whitout deleting them from the array?

Comment: No, you'll have to create some other object(not NSManagedObject or subclass). NSManagedObjects are... hm managed by NSManagedObjectContext and they exist only in the bounds of that context (for example you can not directly pass an NSManagedObject created in one NSManagedObjectContext to another along with they are nothing without a NSManagedObjectContext).

Comment: Ok, the problem is solved, but it's like can't answer my own post... (not enough reputation, so I took a print screen, but can someone put this as an answer? :) ) thanks! http://cl.ly/image/2c1m0W3G3N3U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects will not be written (or "saved") in the sqlite db that backs Core Data, until you save your Managed Object Context. No pint in checking out the db until you call save on it.